# Grails criteria builder

Tags: grails, criteria, builder

I have the folowing:

```
class Store{

String name
}

class Shop{
String name
Store store
}
```

My criteria builder:

```
def c = Shop.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    like("name", "Harrods")
    like("store.name", "McDonals")
}
```

I'm sure this is invalid cause i'v tested it. How can i manage to use criteriaBuilder and do this: like(**"store.name"**, "McDonals")?

Looking forward to get any help,
John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're querying an association, try:

```
def results = c.list {
    like('name', 'Harrods')
    store {
        like('name', 'McDonals')
    }
}
```

This will do an conjoined query between name and store.name.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.4.2%20Criteria) Looks like you need to use a `%` for your like clause.